# How to prevent my Form from submitting with Enter Key in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I always try `$event` in Vue.js but it never worked for me.

This is my Register Form html script :

```
  <form @submit.prevent="RegisterUser($event)" name="register-form" novalidate>
    <div class="accordion" role="tablist">
      <AccountCredentials />
    </div>
  </form>
```

My Register function :

```
async RegisterUser(e) {
  console.log('event', e.keyCode); // got undefined
  if (e.keyCode !== 13) { // I wanna execute this code while it's not enter key
    
    if (this.v_isAllRegisterStepsValid() === true) {
      // REGISTER USER IF FORM IS VALID
      await store.dispatch('auth/UserRegister');
      if (this.is_user_registered === false) {
        this.mx_setModalOptions('Register Failed', this.register_msg, true); // show modal
      }
    }
    else { // SHOW ERROR MESSAGE IF FORM IS NOT VALID
      this.v_showStepsValidationError();
    } // end else
  }
},
```

When I hit the Enter button, my Form submits.

`e.keyCode` got `undefined` How can I prevent submit with Enter button ?

Comment: just use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour

Comment: @SAM that's what `.prevent=` modifier does

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` do not prevent the function's work

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated, try `e.key`

Comment: `this.v_isAllRegisterStepsValid())` --> syntax error?

Comment: it's just another function, it works

Comment: `e.key` got `undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231976/discussion-between-aymane-lassfar-and-t-j).

Comment: You don't have `keycode` on the [`submit` event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-submit)! Don't confuse the `submit` event with whatever event is triggering it, which could be a `keyup`, a `click` or simply calling the `submit()` method on the `<form>` element. Each of them behave differently, but they all trigger the same `submit` event. One more thing: as already pointed out in prior comments, `.prevent` already calls `.preventDefault()` on the submit event, so you don't need to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly linked the `submit()` method above. The proper link to the event is [this one](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#submitevent),

Answer (score 1):

Tried out your code and seeing what `$event` actually contains... (you can do that too, by console logging `e` in your `RegisterUser` function). It does not contain keycode or key, nothing that really distinguishes if you have pressed enter or a button. There is a property called `submitter`, that though if you press enter and have a submit button present, it will always return the button element... Hmm.

So what I figured you could do is to actually make the submit button a regular button with setting `type='button'`, call the same function that you would on submit. By the way, no need to add `$event` as the parameter, that comes along automatically :)

Seems you have a child component as your form, so I assume you have the submit button there? If so, you need to either move the submit button to the parent (I would do that). You can use [`slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) if needed. If you want to keep button in child, then you would need to `$emit` the event to the parent... Anyway, the solution below has the submit button in the parent:

```
<form @submit.prevent="RegisterUser">
  <AccountCredentials />
  <button type="button" @click="RegisterUser">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in the function we check if the type of the event is `click` (the button) or `submit` (the enter press):

```
RegisterUser(e) {
  if (e.type === 'submit') {
    console.log('enter has been pressed!');
    // do stuff!
  }
  else if (e.type === 'click') {
    console.log('button clicked!');
    // do stuff!
  } else {
    console.log('Sorry, I dont know what happened!');
  }
},
```